# Running a program in linux (debian) on startup

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I would like to point out that I tried A LOT of different tutorials from the internet but they don't seem to work...

Adding stuff to init.d, rc.local etc. for some reason it doesn't work.

I'm really desperate to get this done, but I'm a total noob when it comes to linux.

when I type in "matchbox-keyboard" it runs just fine and as intended.

That's literally all I want, but I'd like to run it every time so when I turn my raspberry pi on, I won't have to connect a keyboard and a mouse to initialize on-screen keyboard.

Is there a simple way to get this done, something like dropping the program into autostart folder in windows?

I have no experience with linux at all, I don't know how to write scrips and all that stuff and all I want is to run this "matchbox-keyboard" after every reboot...

Please help me, I'm really desperate and I can't figure it out. Spent all day doing it and still nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to drop in a new cronjob (a cronjob is a task that is scheduled to run at a particular time):

```
crontab -e
```

This allows you to edit your cron file. Instead of putting in a time, use `@reboot`. So you should have a new line in your cronjob file that looks like this:

```
@reboot matchbox-keyboard
```

The cronjobs run in a different environment from your login environment, so you may need to use the full path to the program. I'm also not familiar with the `matchbox-keyboard` program, but it looks like it will run fine since it can run as a background process.

Comment: when I type "cron -e" it says: "cron: invalid option -'e' usage:cron

Comment: Hm. Might be `crontab -e` on a raspberry pi (which I don't have on hand at the moment).

Comment: crontab -e worked. I've added that line and now it's rebooting. Fingers crossed, thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have *gnome-tweaks* installed?

```
apt list gnome-tweaks
Listing... Done
gnome-tweaks/stable,now 3.30.2-1 all [installed,automatic]
```

It has a graphical **Startup Applications** function that allows you to select application icons and start them at **LOGIN** time. I use it to start my favorite text editor.

Starting things like an Apache server (e.g. XAMPP) at **BOOT** time is a whole new ball game. I used [this](https://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian) link as a starting point.